# I'm trying to start a new 2D Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I want to start a new Unity 2D game project. However, I'm wondering rather I'll use the 3D template of Unity or the 2D template of Unity. I heard some 2D games are made of 3D template. Are there benefits when using a 3D template in a 2D project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using 3d project is an advantage as you can imagine how easy it would be easy to setup a 2d game in 3d project.

Comment: What are the advantages?